# Set a page margins

Tags: css, margins

I have [this stylesheet](https://github.com/ask/celery/blob/master/docs/_theme/celery/static/celery.css_t), but the right and left margins are too large (about 5 cm), I don't know how to reduce them. I'd like to have 3 cm right and left.
I tried to change `page_width`, but it did't work.
Thanks,
rubik

Comment: ...what's `.css_t` as a file-extension?

Comment: It is for Sphinx (http://sphinx.pocoo.org/), but is a normal css file

Comment: Does that mean your question is specific to generating something (PDF maybe?) with Sphinx, and not about CSS for printing direct from typical web browsers?

Comment: No, I want to view it in the browser...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, well number one your

```
div.document {
    width: {{ page_width }}px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

is set to `margin: 0 auto;` which makes it centered so your page will be `940px` and will be centered (Resizing your page will confirm this). You probably have to change your content width along with the wrapper width, but keep in mind that the amount of padding depends on how large your viewport is.

### Alternate

If you just want to make it strictly 3cm on the left and right sides and make the content in the middle have a fluid layout you can do this:

```
        margin: 0 3cm;
        position: absolute;
        width: auto;
```